# Not sure where to autogenerate Primary Keys in Room

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I am a beginner of Android development and I am trying to write a Notes demo app following the app architecture of [this example by Google](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-apps/tree/master/DevBytesWorkManager).

According to the example, the ViewModel should access the model defined in the *domain* package i.e. the ViewModel doesn't need to know what the model is like from the API or the Database. (At least that's what I understand from the tutorial)

So in my Note app, I have data class in the domain package and database package. (which are essentially the same)

```
data class Note (
    val id: Long,
    val title: String,
    val body: String
)
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes_table")
data class DatabaseNote constructor(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0L,
    var title: String = "TITLE",
    var body: String = "BODY"
)
```

To create a new note in the ViewModel, I need to create a new Note object, where the id is required! 
My question is, should I just create a DatabaseNote object from the ViewModel, so I can autogenerate an id?
If that's the case, what's the point of the domain model?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the id nullable

```
data class Note (
    val id: Long?,
    val title: String,
    val body: String
)
```

the database will then create one for you when an id is not supplied